# How do I get last commit date from git repository?

Tags: git, git-commit

I need the last commit date in git. This means the latest update date in my program.

I used the command : $ `git log -1` but this command will give me the date from the local repository.  Rather I need date from remote repository.

I tried some commands as follow.

```
git log -n 1 origin/Sprint-6.
git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```

Comment: you can always use ```gitk --all``` to open the tree view for all branches (including remotes)

Answer (score 53):

### Get the last commit date:

You want the "repository wide last commit date for a given git user and git project, for a given branch. For example the date is shown at the top when you visit your repo and go to `commits -> master` for example:

https://github.com/sentientmachine/TeslaAverageGainByMonthWeekDay/commits/master

### Get the last local commit date in git using terminal

Use `git help log` for more info on format codes to pass to `--format` to tell git log what kind of data to fetch.

The last commit date in git:

```
git log -1 --format="%at" | xargs -I{} date -d @{} +%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S
#prints 2018/07/18 07:40:52
```

But as you pointed out, you have to run that command on the machine that performed the last commit.  If the last commit date was performed on another machine, the above command only reports local last commit... So:

### Or Repository wide: Get the last git commit date

Same as above, but do a git pull first

```
git pull; 
git log -1 --format="%at" | xargs -I{} date -d @{} +%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S
#prints 2018/07/18 09:15:10
```

### Or use the JSON API:

Doing `git pull`s is very slow and you're banging GitHub with a heavy operation.  Just query the GitHub rest api:

```
#assuming you're using github and your project URL is visible to public:
# https://github.com/yourusername/your_repo_name

#then do:
curl https://api.github.com/repos/yourusername/your_repo_name/commits/master
```

That blasts you in the face with a screen full of json, so send it your favorite json parser and get the field called `date`:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<your_name>/<your_repo>/commits/master 2>&1 | \
grep '"date"' | tail -n 1
#prints "date": "2019-06-05T14:38:19Z"
```

### From comments below, `gedge` has handy dandy improvements to incantations:

```
git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d %T" --format="%ad"
2019/11/13 15:25:44
```

Or even simpler: ( https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/1.8.0 )

```
git --no-pager log -1 --format="%ai"
2019-12-13 09:08:38 -0500
```

Your choices are north, south, east, and "Dennis".

Comment: Just curious; any special reason for using `xargs`?                                                        I am thinking `date -d @\`git log -1 --format="%at"\`` will be a more concise solution.

Comment: My choice of `xargs` was a blend of google-fu, guess and check, and brownian motion.  Your solution appears to remove unnecessary layers of the onion.  Have an up boat.

Comment: For Mac OSX, date is different and will not work. You might want to use `DT=\`git log -1 --format="%at"\` && python -c "import time; print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime($DT)))"`

Comment: This osx command needs more layers.  Maybe you can add a javascript ajax hit to mongodb so that is more webscale.

Comment: sarcasm when using `xargs...date`? when this would do: `git log -1 --date=format:"%Y/%m/%d %T" --format="%ad"`

Comment: As `date` is a `one-liner`, can we output without `less-style` just printing it and the cursor moves to the beginning of a new terminal line ready to rumble?

Comment: At the end of Erics answer you see a nice flag to output without `less`: `--no-pager`.

Answer (score 8):

#### To get the last commit date from git repository in a long(Unix epoch timestamp)

- **Command:** `git log -1 --format=%ct`
- **Result:** `1605103148`

**Note:** You can visit the [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation to get a more detailed description of the options.

Answer (score 7):

`git log -1` will give you the Merge id, Author and Date

```
git log -1 --format=%cd
```

**Output:** `Wed Apr 13 15:32:54 2022 +0530`

We can format the date as below:

```
git --no-pager log -1 --pretty='format:%cd' --date='format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

**Output:** `2022-04-13 15:32:54`

Comment: Hello @Divya - thank you for your contribution, but your answer is a duplicate of already existing answers.

Comment: It's not fully identical to any of the other answers, and contains the optimal solution in the most concise way

Answer (score 3):

Another oneliner for Linux, get UTC ISO 8601 time formatted up to the minutes:

`TZ=utc date -d @$(git log -1 --format=%ct) --iso-8601=m`

Gives `2022-12-07T10:01+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here's how to get the UNIX timestamp of the latest remote commit:

```
git log -1 --date=raw origin/master | grep ^Date | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using git version 2.39.2 .

As I set up my `~/.gitconfig` with `showSignature = true`, executing `git log -1 --format=%cI` will additionally include commit signature information, e.g.

```
Good "git" signature for abdull@example.com with RSA key SHA256:abcd
2023-04-14T20:02:23+02:00
```

To remove the commit signature information, add the `--no-show-signature` flag, e.g. `git log --no-show-signature -1 --format=%cI`:

```
2023-04-14T20:02:23+02:00
```