# Auto-include version of program based on date of git push

Tags: c, git, gcc

I am developing a program in C that needs to include the date and the time of the last push performed in a given branch in the git repository in order to version it.

I know how I can get the data from git and use it to generate a version number in the format I want.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51403241/7114946)

The problem is I don't know how to include this within the code of the program because it ultimately needs to "printf" this info during the starting of the app.

I have found the preprocessor macros `__TIME__` and `__DATE__`. I wonder if there are other similar macros to include some given string/data.

Thanks

edit: I need to include this info in compilation time, not when the code is uploaded into git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define macros on the command line:

```
gcc -DFOO=BAR -c prog.c
```

acts like `#define FOO BAR` in `prog.c`.

You can combine this with shell command interpolation to get the output of an external program in there:

```
gcc -DGIT_TIMESTAMP="\"$(git whateveryourcommandis)\"" prog.c
```

(The escaped quotes are there to make the macro expand to a string literal.)

And then `prog.c` can do e.g.:

```
printf("my git timestamp is %s\n", GIT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I am just lurking but that is slick.

Comment: That is exactly what i was searching for

Precise, concise and clean.

Thank you!