# How can I get a list of git repositories, sorted by commit time?

Tags: php, linux, git

I set up my own server to host some private git repositories.

I am working on a visual representation (using a php backend) of my private 'repo base'.
It all works fine and I may open-source it at some point.

---

My current issue: Creating a list of all repositories (I did that already), which is sorted by the last commit times (to the master-branches).

I currently use this function to get a list of my (bare) git repositories:

```php
function listRepositories() {
  global $SYSTEM_PATH;

  exec("ls $SYSTEM_PATH/repos/ -t", $repoDirectories);

  $repos = array_map(function($repo) {
    return str_replace("$SYSTEM_PATH/repos/", "", $repo);
  }, $repoDirectories);

  return $repos;
}
```

However, the `ls $SYSTEM_PATH/repos/ -t` command I currently use to get a list of repos does not sort them the way I want.
If I copy older repos into the repository directory (`$SYSTEM_PATH/repos/`), they appear on top of the list.

This command returns the last commit time (unix timestamp):

```
git log -1 --format=%ct
```

However, I did not yet manage to combine all that to achieve what I want in a efficient way.

---

*Thank you for helping me achieve it, I am grateful for everything this community taught me!*

---

**Related Questions:**

- Last git commit time: [How do I get last commit date from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25563455/12787264)
- The same for branches: [How can I get a list of Git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5188320/12787264)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into every repository in a loop, output the last commit timestamp in a sortable format (let's use unix time), sort and output sorted repo names:

```
find $SYSTEM_PATH/repos/ -maxdepth 1 -type d |
while read repo; do
    git -C "$repo" --no-pager log -1 --format="%ct $repo" 2>/dev/null
done | sort -nr | awk '{print $2}'
```